# Alias console.log function and print the name of an argument

Tags: javascript, console

I thought, that it might be possible to extend regular console.log function to make it print the name of consolling variable.

E.g. that what I do right now to understand wich variable is being printed:

```
    for (var k in obj) {
     console.log('obj[k].a', obj[k].a);  
     console.log('obj[k].b', obj[k].b);  
     console.log('obj[k].c', obj[k].c);  
     console.log('obj[k].d', obj[k].d); 
     console.log('-------------');
//I put the string first, and then the value - it's really usefull when I have to debug very long function with lots of cycles and variables. But it takes time typing all those console.log functions :(
    }
```

Is it possible to extend wondow.console function or create an alias function that will not only be shorter, but also will typout the name of consolling variable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
for (var k in obj) {
 console.log('obj["'+k+'"]', obj[k]);  
}
```